# What the Heck is wrong with my (not to complex) MySQL-Query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, natural-join

I might be blind on both eyes, but iterating through a lot of versions and tries... Deleted the hyphenation and the AS statements...

I always ended up with a parsing Error 1064 from my MySql5.1 Server.
I really believe this is valid, SQL Answers:

Are there any suggestions?

```
SELECT (dpa_articles.name, [...] corporations.isin) FROM corporations 
NATURAL JOIN corporations_dpa_articles ON (corporations.id = corporations_dpa_articles.corporation_id)
NATURAL JOIN dpa_articles ON (dpa_articles.id = corporations_dpa_articles.dpa_article_id)
NATURAL JOIN dpa_articles_dpa_categories ON (dpa_articles.id = dpa_articles_dpa_categories.dpa_article_id)
WHERE dpa_articles_dpa_categories.dpa_category_id = 28
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON (corporations.id=corporations_dpa_articles.corporation_id)
>   NATURAL JOIN dpa_a' at line 3

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: read this http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqljoin/mysql-natural-join.shtml may the natural join doesn't need the `ON () clause`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NATURAL JOIN` should not have an `ON` clause.

The joining condition is implicit and based on column names.

You need `INNER JOIN` as the column names are different. `id` will not natural join to `corporation_id`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try un-wrapping the `ON` clause in the join statements?

Also, you may want to consider using a different join than a `natural join`. `Natural join`s don't give you quite as much control as other join methods, and I am not sure if specifying the column it joins on is even valid. An `inner join` *may* be more appropriate.